# php - correct search expression for bbpress

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I have a very purdy styled search box in my wordpress install, and looking for continuity I want the same for my bbpress forum - currently I'm failing.

For WP I have:

```
        <div id="search">
        <form action="<?php bloginfo('home') ?>" method="get">
    <div class="hiddenFields"></div>
    <p><input name="s" id="s"  maxlength="100" size="18" /><input class="submit" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="submit" /></p></form>
    </div>
```

For bbPress The form 'method="get">' gets kicked out and of-course I need another expression.  bbpress generally seems to use:

```
            <div class="search"><?php search_form(); ?></div>
```

This wrecks everything - I get no styling attributes at all other than position...
I can make it look fine (and consistent) with by removing the  - but then it's obviously just a dummy with no search - any ideas to fix the latter?
Thanks

```
<div id="search">

    <div class="hiddenFields"></div>
    <p><input name="s" id="s"  maxlength="100" size="18" /><input class="submit" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the search-form.php file in your theme file to display the search form. You can style it there and if the file doesn't exist in your theme file, it uses the one from default theme.

Comment: search.php does exist my theme.  what I need is the expression to call it without destroying the styling I already have on the front-page, which the search_form() expression does.  All my comments refer to front-page...

Answer (score 0):

> search.php does exist my theme

@billn, was that a typo?

As @AshFame said, create a file named `searchform.php` in your theme folder, and `search_form()` will load that instead of the default.